# Predetermine UITableViewCell height for nonexistant UILabel with unfilled text property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Using the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` I have the text that is going to be placed in a UILabel that *will* be drawn **afterwards** in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Here's my question. If my UILabel is not drawn until after `heightForRow..` (cellForRow), and I'm using `[myLabel sizeToFit]` to resize the UILabel, then how can I calculate the Label's height before `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `sizeToFit:` are called, within the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?

In other words, how do I predict what the UILabel's height will be after the text has been set and sizeToFit has been called before **either** are called? or am I going about this wrong?

- Note: This question does not pertain to readjusting a UILabel, it pertains to appropriately calculating the height needed for a UITableViewCell given the text that *will* fill a UILabel, a label of which it's height, *will* not be determined until after the `.text` property is set and `[myLabel sizeToFit:]` has been called.

Comment: Why are you not using autolayout and auto-sizing cells? Then you will not have to calculate any cell heights as it will be done for you.

Comment: Didn't realize I wasn't, investigating that right now

Comment: @RoboticCat how do you enable this programmatically?

Comment: You didn't read the question. This has nothing to do with resizing an UILabel. That code is already in affect and has nothing to do with the question.